Reload module that is imported into __init__.py
What works: I have a package version_info in which I define a string version_info. When I increment version_info.version_info, the main code prints out the incremented value after the reload.
What doesn't work: When I increment the value in version_info_sub.py, it is not updated upon reload.
I suspect that the importlib.reload doesn't go accross the from .sub import version_info_sub statement.
How can I achieve that also the value from sub.py gets reloaded?
Main code:
from importlib import reload
import version_info
...
reload(version_info)
print(version_info.version_string) # successfully updated
print(version_info.version_info_sub) # stays on the old value

version_info/__init__.py:
from .sub import version_info_sub
version_string = "6"

version_info/sub.py:
version_info_sub = "6"


With "increment" you mean to edit the source file manually? What happens in the first snippet at ...? Is this just an input() to pause execution or something else?

I think in the version_info/__init__.py
you did not want to write version_string = "6" right?
sorry if I am mistaken.

I think I got your problem.
I made a reload_package function for you.
import inspect

def reload_package(package_):
    modules_names_paths = inspect.getmembers(package_, inspect.ismodule)
    modules_names = [x[0] for x in modules_names_paths]
    for module_name in modules_names:
        module_ = getattr(package_, module_name)
        reload(module_)
    reload(package_)

The problem is that you reload the package but the sub module is not reloaded.
You could reload the sub also.
But in order to be agnostic (I guess the caller does not have to know about "sub") you will have to loop over the modules in the package, reload them and then reload the package.
This function will do.
Happy Coding

modules_names_paths contains a name and a path for every element.
So I had to clear the paths and keep only the names in the [0] zero index.

The problem is that python copies the variables and their values into the module you're importing to. This means that when you reload only version_info, you are just getting the old value back. An easy fix to this is to reload the submodule first
reload(version_info.sub)
reload(version_info)

